# What is the idiomatic way to convert a Some into a None given a predicate in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to be able to convert a `Some` to a `None`, if some certain condition holds true for the value within the Some.

For example if I have `Some(false)` it should be turned into a `None`, while `Some(true)` should remain as `Some(true)`

I found some way to do this.

```
let value1: Option<bool> = Some(false);
let value2: Option<bool> = Some(true);

let result1 = value1.and_then(|inner| if inner == false { None } else { Some(inner) });
let result2 = value2.and_then(|inner| if inner == false { None } else { Some(inner) });

println!("{:?}", result1); // Prints "None"
println!("{:?}", result2); // Prints "Some(true)"
```

or even this

```
let value1: Option<bool> = Some(false);
let value2: Option<bool> = Some(true);

let result1 = if let Some(false) = value1 { None } else { value1 };
let result2 = if let Some(false) = value2 { None } else { value2 };

println!("{:?}", result1); // Prints "None"
println!("{:?}", result2); // Prints "Some(true)"
```

Looked around the docs' and I could not find a method that does this in a more succinct way.

Something like

```
let value = Some(v).to_none_if(predicate)

where value will be None, if predicate is true
or value will remain Some(v) if predicate is false
```

What will be the most idiomatic way in Rust to do this type of transformation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`filter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.filter), although it does the opposite of what you're asking: it converts to `None` if the predicate returns **`false`**. So you need to negate the expression:

```rust
let v = option.filter(|&v| !(v == false));
```

Or just:

```rust
let v = option.filter(|&v| v);
```